# Troubling navigation bar, tool bar inside tabbar

Tags: ios

If I use navigation bar , tool bar normally it works with out any problem, but if i try to use same in side tabbarcontroller or try to show modally(which slides from bottom), the tool bar, navigation bar then do not show. Table view works fine, other controls works fine. Can any buddy help me out what is going wrong that is causing such strange behavior. I tried several time also searched on internet but issue still exist.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 44)];
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
    titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
    titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    if ([[self appDelegate] connect]) 
    {
        titleLabel.text = [[[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] myJID] bare];
    } else
    {
        titleLabel.text = @"No JID";
    }

    [titleLabel sizeToFit];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
}
```

Comment: Is this code in your modal view controller?  If the view arrives without a navigation bar then setting a title on the navigationItem won't benefit you.  You have to make sure it has a navigationBar first.

Answer (score 0):

When you push something on modally it creates a completely new view on top of your other view.  It will not inherit the tool bar from the navigation controller that you pushed it on top of.  Instead, try to push the view onto the navigation controller (where it animates it in from the right.)  Pushing it on to the navigation controller makes it easier to inherit the toolbar.  Otherwise, if you want to keep a tool bar on your modal view presentation you will have to create the toolbar yourself separately for this new view.